# How to show full subtree in Org 9.3.3

Tags: org-mode

I want to access the first entry of a `:LOGBOOK:` drawer independently of the visibility of a subtree: folded, partially folded, or unfolded. This function worked on 9.1.9 in the first two cases (folded and partially folded):

```lisp
(defun my-org-clock-goto-next-clock ()
  (interactive)
  (org-back-to-heading)
  (search-forward "LOGBOOK:")
  (org-cycle 3)
  (forward-line)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  )
```

I upgraded to Org mode 9.3.3 and `(org-cycle 3)` no longer unfolds a subtree.  At a top-level heading, I see a message:

```
Already at the top level of the outline
```

I read [the manual on local and global visibility cycling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html#Global-and-local-cycling) and could not find how to set a subtree to unfolded.

What is the command to unfold all contents of a subtree regardless of the initial state?

Comment: Try `(outline-show-subtree)` instead of `(org-cycle 3)`.

Comment: BTW, the doc string for `org-cycle` says: `When there is a numeric prefix, go up to a heading with level ARG, do
a ‘show-subtree’ and return to the previous cursor position.  If ARG
is negative, go up that many levels.` That probably explains the error, but I don't know why it worked for 9.1.9 - probably an accident.

Comment: I believe drawers are folded independently of structure: most people seem to want them folded even if the subtree is unfolded, so you have to do something extra to open them: try calling  `(org-cycle)` when point is on the drawer name (i.e. after the `(search-forward ...)` or the `(outline-show-subtree)` since the latter returns point to where it was before the call).

Comment: Maybe `org-flag-drawer` can be used instead: try `(org-flag-drawer nil)`. `org-cycle` delegates to it in the case of a drawer. I'll try to get a decent answer written but it won't be before the weekend.

Comment: Done, and I deleted my comments to keep a tidy thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, you are looking for `(outline-show-subtree)` in the general case:

> `(outline-show-subtree)`
>
> Show everything after this heading at deeper levels.

In case of a drawer, which most people want folded even when the tree is unfolded, use `(org-flag-drawer nil)`:

> `(org-flag-drawer FLAG &optional ELEMENT BEG END)`
>
> When `FLAG` is non-nil, hide the drawer we are at. Otherwise make it
>   visible.

`org-cycle` delegates to `org-flag-drawer` in the case of a drawer.

You may need to call them in a different order, or when point is at the location you want unfolded.

For my case, the solution was:

```lisp
(defun my-org-clock-goto-next-clock ()
  (interactive)
  (org-back-to-heading)
  (search-forward "LOGBOOK:")
  (outline-show-subtree)
  (org-flag-drawer nil)
  (forward-line)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  )
```

It's probably an accident that `(org-cycle 3)` worked for 9.1.9, since the doc string for `org-cycle` says:

> When there is a numeric prefix, go up to a heading with level ARG, do a ‘show-subtree’ and return to the previous cursor position. If ARG is negative, go up that many levels.

That probably explains the error in 9.3.3.